# How to perform MitM against SSL/TLS when certificate owned?

Tags: tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle, kali-linux, sslstrip

Performing a local network man-in-the-middle (MitM) attack is fairly straightforward, especially when the traffic is unencrypted HTTP. There are other approaches to encrypted SSL/TLS HTTPS connections, such as using SSLStripper.

My question is, provided I own the HTTP certificate, for example to my own website, how could I MitM clients on my network to read their traffic? I would assume that since I own the certificate then decryption would be straight forward, unless they are using a VPN or similar privacy enhancing technology.

This could either be decrypted on the fly, or saved so I can decrypt it at a later date, either approach is fine.

EDIT: Assume I own the private key, sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: It's not really a man in the middle. If you own the certificate they're sending you their data. It's already decrypted on your end.

Comment: @RoraΖ Perhaps a better example would be if the SSL/TLS certificate was stolen from www.google.com, so the attacker cannot see the data at the end on Google's servers, but they do have the certificate so surely they could somehow use it to decrypt traffic...

Comment: If you have a certificate for a site that the browser trusts, and you have the corresponding private key, then you can use a tool like [sslsniff](https://github.com/moxie0/sslsniff) to MITM the connection to the site.

Comment: @mti2935 ./sslsniff -t -s <$listenPort> -w <$logFile> -m google.crt -c <$certDir> like this, provided the attacker somehow obtained google's cert which is unlikely.

Comment: @questioner That looks right.  FWIW, anyone can download Google's cert (see https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website).  The hard part is getting Google's private key.

Comment: @mti2935 Oh, so if I had the private key, how would I change the above command? Sorry, I assumed the google.crt was my imaginary private key.

Comment: @questioner If the private key file is in $certDir, sslsniff will find it there.

Comment: @mti2935 Oh, okay. Sorry, you confused me with your earlier comment with the link containing Google's cert.

Answer (score 1):

> This could either be decrypted on the fly, or saved so I can decrypt it at a later date, either approach is fine.

You're gonna have to go with decrypted on the fly. The certificate + private key is not enough information to store-and-decrypt-later. The reason is that (modern) TLS certificates are *authentication / signature* certificates which is an independent step of the TLS handshake from the key exchange that establishes the session encryption keys. This is a property known as [perfect forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).

You'll need to do this:

- Set up a proxy that uses the victim server's certificate + priv key.
- Manipulate the network so that the victim user's traffic flows through the proxy.

  - Note that the client needs to think it's talking to the real server's hostname, otherwise the cert hostname SAN check will fail. So this needs to be a TCP or IP level manipulation, like a hostfile entry pointing `server.com` to the IP of the proxy, or a DNS poisoning so that `server.com` resolves to the IP of the proxy, or an ARP / BGP attack so that the proxy advertizes itself as a low-cost router / gateway for routing traffic to `server.com`'s IP.

---

Tools-wise with what comes in Kali, you could consider a setup like this:

```
client --1:tls--> Kali[ncat1--2:non-tls--> ncat2] --3:tls--> server.com
```

where you put the server's cert and priv key on ncat1, and use wireshark to inspect link 2.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but would it perhaps be easier to do this: ./sslsniff -t -s <$listenPort> -w <$logFile> -m google.crt -c <$certDir> where the $certDir has the private key of, in this example, Google.

Comment: @questioner Dunno, I've never used sslsniff before.